# I need the contents in a single page before the title of the article with page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add a Contents table along with page numbers in a single page before the tile of my article.

**I have used the following Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}
\topmargin=0.02cm 
\textwidth=17cm
\textheight=23cm
\baselineskip=11pt
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.01pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.01pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calligra}
\newtheorem{fig}{figure}[section]
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\title{Term Paper}
\author{Mathuser}
\maketitle 
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

The code with special code `\tableofcontents` but this does not give subsections and subsubsections. Also I need the contents in a single page before the title of the article with page numbers.

Do I need these format or book format?
[image]

Comment: You wrote *but this does not give subsections and subsubsections.* This is because you didn't use `\subsection{}` neither `\subsubsection{}`. How it could be in contents if you didn't insert anywhere. But, if you don't want them like in my second page below, simply delete it.

Comment: Sir, this page is the 2nd page which I attached and I do not want the box part  in the 2nd part and I want the content only in the first page.

Comment: Sorry. I suggest you to learn a little bit about basic LaTeX. You are confusing the contents with the ((sub)sub)section's header. I can only suggest you to delete the lines `\subsection{title}` and `\subsubsection{title}` if you don't want them.

Comment: It is ok. Thanks for your good effort to make me understand but I did not get it fully though it was helpful

Comment: Looking at the comments to the answer below, i have to say... This question is more than confusing.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475443/table-of-contents-in-middle-of-the-page-and-in-larger-font-size Seems you have managed what you want. Can we close this question?

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\maketitle
```

to insert title page in a new page. Also, move `\author{}` and `\title{}` to preamble (ie., before `\begin{document}`).

To print subsections and subsubsection on table of contents you have to change the `tocdepth` counter.

[image]

So,

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}
% .... your full preamble here

\title{Term Paper}          % <--- moved to here
\author{Mathuser}           % <--- moved to here

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    % <--- added

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage                  % <--- added
\maketitle 
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{title}          % <--- added
\subsubsection{title}       % <--- added
\end{document}
```

Comment: This gives a new page of the content but same content (repeatedly) again is being appeared in the introduction part after the 'tile' $Mathuser$. Can you check by running it?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, please, do like I did, use the commands `\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\maketitle ` only once in that order and compile twice to update the table of contents.

Comment: I request to run the code in your machine in order to see the outcome. Your code can help me a lot if you check it yourself it. As I said the content section is appearing twice, once before the title page and once in the introduction part. plaese run the code yourself and help me. Otherwise give your email address I will sent you the output PDF file to show the output

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, are you kidding me? Do you think that I didn't compile it? See the screenshot. That *introduction part* is the section head. Type something there and you'll see.

Comment: Sir I am saying that  I want to remove the same content in the  2nd page  of the output (as you attached). I just highlighted the page which i want to remove. Please see the attched page in my answer part, I want to remove the part within highlighted box

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, your claims are wrong (and rude). To clarify what suggested solution shows on the second page please add in its preamble `\usepackage{lipsum}` and then after `\section{...}`, \subsection{...}` and `subsubsection{...}` command line `\lipsum[11]` (which generate 11th paragraph from dummy text) and then observe difference between the first and second page.

Comment: Nice and concise answer (+1). Just a small idea,: it may be easier for the OP to notice difference between first and second page if you would add some dummy text after each `\section..` command.