# Table of Contents in middle of the page and in larger font size?

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, fontsize

How to display the contents page in middle of the page and in large size than the other font size within the `article`?

I have used the command `\tableofcontents`.

The output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Are you displaying the desired output, or the actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `\vspace*{\fill}` before and after the `\tableofcontents`, and a `\newpage` after the second `\vspace*{\fill}`, is an easy way to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    % May also want \newpage here (e.g. if title page before toc)
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \tableofcontents
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage % Page break between toc and first section
    \section{Introduction}
    \section{Abstract Algebra}
    \section{p-adic numbers}
    \section{Concept}
    \section{Algebraic Closure}
\end{document}
```

As noted in the code, if you have content before the toc (e.g. a titlepage), you will also want a `\newpage` *before* the first `\vspace*{\fill}`.

Output:

[image: output]